# Gson.fromJson() - throw Exception if Type is different

Tags: java, gson

I've created REST service which returns `ExceptionEntity` serialized class as a result if something gone wrong.

I want to throw some exception if json which should be deserialized by `Gson.fromJson()` is in different type. For example I've got this string which should be deserialized (my.ExceptionEntity.class):

```
{"exceptionId":2,"message":"Room aaaa already exists."}
```

but I use `Room` class as type for this serialized string:

```
String json = "{\"exceptionId\":2,\"message\":\"Room aaaa already exists.\"}";
Room r = gson.fromJson(json, Room.class);
// as a result r==null but I want to throw Exception; how?
```

**[EDIT]**
I've tested this and it doesn't work:

```
try {
    return g.fromJson(roomJson, new TypeToken<Room>(){}.getType());
    // this also doesn't work
    // return g.fromJson(roomJson, Room.class);
} catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
    pepuch.multiplayergame.entity.Exception ex = g.fromJson(roomJson, pepuch.multiplayergame.entity.Exception.class);
    throw ExceptionController.toGameServerException(ex);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    pepuch.multiplayergame.entity.Exception ex = g.fromJson(roomJson, pepuch.multiplayergame.entity.Exception.class);
    throw ExceptionController.toGameServerException(ex);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [let Gson throw exceptions on wrong types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242236/let-gson-throw-exceptions-on-wrong-types)

Comment: This will only throw JsonSyntaxException. You do not need to catch JsonParseException

Answer (score 17):

According to GSon [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-) an exception is already thrown if the json stream can't be deserialized according to the type you provided:

> Throws:
>   `JsonParseException` - if json is not a valid representation for an object of type classOfT

But this is an unchecked exception, if you want to provide a custom exception you should try with

```
try {
  Room r = gson.fromJson(json, Room.class);
}
catch (JsonParseException e) {
  throw new YourException();
}
```

Comment: I've edited my questiom. I've tested this and it doesn't work.

Comment: You could try with `Room r = gson.fromJson(..); if (r == null) throw new Exception(..);`

Comment: Yes, you're right but this is wrong :/ Documentation says that those methods should throws `JsonParseException` but they don't :/ As I know `null validation` is a bad pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert it to Json first then convert it to the object type you want.

```
val newJson = Gson().toJson(json)
```

val r = gson.fromJson(json, Room.class)