# GSON: How to identify that JSON members **amount** is greater than Model members amount

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

1. Problem:
   How to identify that my Model object (POJO) members **amount** is not equal to the JSON members.
2. Notes:

- Fields name mismatch - Gson build-in feature;
- I have found few custom adapters implementations but they solve other issues like
  [let Gson throw exceptions on wrong types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242236/let-gson-throw-exceptions-on-wrong-types) but it required to annotate each filed with the annotation "JsonRequired", smells as overhead for Models within 20 members and at least 100 classes;
  and this
  [let Gson throw exceptions on wrong types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242236/let-gson-throw-exceptions-on-wrong-types) is more about the handling the problem of the time-to-time member appearing in a Model;
  and this one
  [Detect if deserialized object is missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030712/detect-if-deserialized-object-is-missing-a-field-with-the-jsonconvert-class-in-j) from .Net is looking like a solution but I looking for Java suggestion/implementation;

3. Purpose:
   It is necessary for the integration level testing needs. I have an expected JSON string, getting the actual JSON string (for example from service) in case if the actual JSON has more members than my model I would like to be aware of this issue, let it be an exception throwing.
4. Code:

**ActualPayLoad.json**

```
{
    "num1": 1,
    "bool1": true,
    "str1": "firstMissedInModel",
    "nested": {
        "num2": 1,
        "bool2": true,
        "str2": "secondMissedInModel"
    }
}
```

**TopModel.class**

```
public class TopModel {

    private Boolean bool1;
    private NestedModel nested;
    private Long num1;
//    private String str1;
}
```

**NestedModel.class**

```
public class NestedModel {
    private Boolean bool2;
    private Long num2;
//    private String str2;
}
```

Thank you for an eforts.

Comment: Please show us how you deserialize json string.

Comment: Like this String actualPayload = new Gson().toJson(actualRs.getActualPayload());